# "\ " and "\@" not working with microtype

Tags: spacing

I noticed that the spacing commands "\ " and "@" are getting ignored when microtype is loaded (i.e. the spaces after periods are too large even with ".\ ").

Since I haven't found anything about this in the documentation, I'm asking here.

Edit: here is a MWE. Looks like it might be a bug in the `nonfrench` spacing feature of microtype (the behavior goes away after commenting the line with `nonfrench`).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[spacing=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}

\begin{document}
An abbreviation, e.g.\ this one using backslash, vs.~this one using tilde. Look identical so far.

Now in a longer paragraph (the difference is visible depending on \texttt{textwidth}):

Hopf fibration in stereographic projection, i.e.\ as a fibration of $R^3$. Each circle is a fiber corresponding to a point on the 2-sphere at the bottom.

Hopf fibration in stereographic projection, i.e.~as a fibration of $R^3$. Each circle is a fiber corresponding to a point on the 2-sphere at the bottom.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Show an example that can be used for tests.

Comment: Which font, which microtype options, etcetera?

Comment: Sorry, I've added a MWE. The issue is clearly in the `nonfrench` spacing option, perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of microtype mentions in section 5.5 Interword spacing

> Note that when interword spacing adjustment is in effect, space
>   factors are ignored.

This means that with the experimental `spacing=nonfrench`  using the `\` method to suppress the space doesn't work. It works with e.g. an `\mbox` or as you already discovered with an unbreakable space `~`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[spacing=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
e. as

e.\ as

e.\mbox{} as

e.~as

\end{document}
```

[image]

The alternative is not to use spacing but the standard `\nonfrenchspacing` setting:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
e. as

e.\ as

e.\mbox{} as

e.~as

\end{document}
```

[image]